# Why isnt my MySQL BETWEEN operator not working?

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL table "flightSched" is connected to time, similar to the one below:

```
flightNo    |day    |time   |arrivalTimeSec
=============================================
WERE112 |Tuesday    | 1:00  |1381186800
FGHG234 |Tuesday    |23:00  |1381266000
CGHF345 |Tuesday    |00:00  |1381183200
```

I have a mysql query that select all data between two times. This is the query:

```
$CurrentTimeMinus30min = date('H:i', strtotime('-30 minutes')); //Current Time minus 30minutes
$CurrentTimeMinus30min = strtotime($CurrentTimeMinus30min);     

$CurrentTimePlus4Hours = date('H:i', strtotime('+240 minutes')); //Current Time plus 4 hours
$CurrentTimePlus4Hours = strtotime($CurrentTimePlus4Hours);

$query = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT * FROM flightSched 
    WHERE day = '$currentDay' 
    AND arrivalTimeSec 
        BETWEEN '$CurrentTimeMinus30min' 
        AND '$CurrentTimePlus4Hours'
");
```

I was advised to used strtotime() function on the time values to be able to use them in a BETWEEN MySQL query. This doesn't seem to be working at all.

Where am I going wrong with this query? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you please
echo $currentTimeMinus30min;
and tell what you are getting

Comment: Are you getting an error or just incorrect results? Also how to you input the data that's in the database? (format)

Comment: @Deepak echo-ing $currentTimeMinus30min; will just print out the current time - 30 minutes. in my TimeZone its currently 12:26 so it echo's out:  "1381310760"

Comment: @SirBT If the values of both time variables are correct try my solution in your between. It could solve the problem.

Comment: @Ruddy I get incorrect results. The time is feed in via an HTML form manually and is stored in the database in TYPE Varchar(8). I hope this answers you question?

Comment: Why are you generating a unit time value, converting it to a string the converting it back to a Unix time value? (twice)

Comment: Your way to calculate the timestamps is quite complicated and you also have redundant fields in your database. See my improved answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

today I found the same problem with yours (mine about coordinates).
and I found out that in some case, a BETWEEN operator can only be used like this

```
..... WHERE columname BETWEEN smallervalue AND biggervalue
```

previously I've tried with the biggervalue at front since I dealt with negative numbers, and it fails.
you might found the same problem with your timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` returns a timestamp so passing that into the MySQL query, like above, won't work. Try using `FROM_UNIXTIME` instead.

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM flightSched 
                    WHERE day = '$currentDay' 
                    AND FROM_UNIXTIME(arrivalTimeSec) BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME($CurrentTimeMinus30min) AND FROM_UNIXTIME($CurrentTimePlus4Hours) " );
```

**EDIT** - I hadn't noticed that `arrivalTimeSec` was also a timestamp. The above mightn't be a workable answer for you, but try it. If it doesn't work, as others say, define what you mean by

> This doesn't seem to be working at all.

Is it not returning any rows? Is it returning an error? Can you print out `$CurrentTimeMinus30min` and `$CurrentTimePlus4Hours`? Narrow down the potential areas for problems.

Comment: Thanks your solution worked! Even with arrivalTimeSec as a timestamp. To answer your question, the Query wasn't returning any  rows or errors indicating that the query wasn't efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to encapsulate the between? This could potentially solve your problem:

```
SELECT * FROM flightSched 
WHERE day = '$currentDay' 
AND (arrivalTimeSec BETWEEN '$CurrentTimeMinus30min' AND '$CurrentTimePlus4Hours')
```

Also why not just do:

```
$CurrentTimeMinus30min = strtotime('-30 minutes');
```

Or

```
$CurrentTimeMinus30min = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:00', strtotime('-30 minutes')));
```

Please send us some examples of what your variables are generating.

Answer (score 0):

Your time calculation with `date("H:i",...)` and `strtotime(..)` seems to actually produce the correct results, although there is a much easier way to add/substract n minutes from the current time:

```
$now = time();
$currentTimeMinus30min = $now - 30*60;    // 30 minutes * 60 seconds
$currentTimePlus4Hours = $now + 4*60*60;  // 4 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds
```

(I assume your time entries in your database are unix timestamps.)

Your query looks fine, too, but there are a few things to keep in mind:

- You have redundant fields in your database (day and time can be calculated from the timestamp)
- Working with time variables can easily lead to confusion, as the time passes on and if you have no entries in your database that match the specified time range (-30m to +240m) the result set is empty. So to test the query update the database with current time stamps.

I would suggest the following:

Drop the redundant columns day and time and just use the timestamp as base for your calculations, because the day and time is already included in the timestamp. So just use a simple query like

```
select * from flightShed
where arrivalTime between $begin and $end
```